# Python: How do you find the simplest form of divisibility

Tags: python

I am working on a program where the user inputs the number of people going on a trip and the program determines the required number of each vehicle type to be used. Saying that:
Car - 4 passengers
Minivan - 7 passengers
Small Bus - 15 passengers
Big Bus - 60 passengers

This is what I have so far:

```
car_capacity = int(4)
minivan_capacity = int(7)
short_bus_capacity = int(15)
full_size_bus_capacity = int(60)

cars_needed = 0
minivan_needed = 0
short_buses_needed = 0
full_size_buses_needed = 0

passengers = int(input("How many people will be going?\n"))
if passengers < 1:
    print("Nobody is going, therefore no vehicles will be needed.")

while passengers > 0:
    print(passengers % 60)
```

Basically I'm trying to find out the fewest Vehicles needed. Ex (Input = 63. Output 1 Big Bus, 1 Small)

Please don't think I'm asking for answers, I just need a clue or a hint of what to research or how to approach this

Comment: I guess you could just do passengers/60, then take the rest of the passengers to do try with a small bus etc...

Comment: Check out [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod). Hint: What's returned if you try `divmod(63,60)`. What about `divmod(76,60)` and `divmod(16, 7)`?

Comment: Shouldn't the fewest vehicles needed in your example (Input=63) be 1 Big Bus and 1 Car?

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist being pedantic. Isn't the smallest number of vehicles always `math.ceil(float(passengers) / 60.0)` big buses? There has to be another criterion that insists I put my leftover passengers in a van instead of a bus, like minimizing total capacity.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. Your question has received answers and could be helpful to other users. If an answer solved your issue, you should "accept" it. If you found a solution yourself, post your own answer. If you *really* have a good reason for this post to be deleted, contact the Stack Overflow support team and tell them why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
passengers = int(input("How many people will be going?\n"))
if passengers < 1:
    print("Nobody is going, therefore no vehicles will be needed.")

# make it a dictionary, so we can loop through
vehicles = {
    4: 'car',
    7: 'minivan',
    15: 'short_bus',
    60: 'full_size_bus'
} 
vehicles_needed = {}

# a helper to check one type of vehicle
def check_vehicle(passengers, capacity, name):
    if passengers >= capacity:
        amount = passengers / capacity
        # substract the passengers 
        passengers -= (amount * capacity)
        return {name: amount}, passengers
    return {}, passengers

# loop through all capacities from the biggest one
for k, v in sorted(vehicles.items(), reverse=True):
    # if any vehicle needed, it will be put in the vehicles_needed
    vehicle_update, passengers = check_vehicle(passengers, k, v)
    vehicles_needed.update(vehicle_update)
# if there is a leftover, add one car
if passengers > 0:
    vehicles_needed.update({'car':  vehicles_needed.get('car', 0) + 1})

print vehicles_needed # 67 -> {'minivan': 1, 'full_size_bus': 1}
```

Comment: Using this solution, I only get decimal answers for more than 60 passengers, instead of two separate vehicle. I'm using version 3 if that changes anything

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: What did you replace from my original and what did you keep? or was your answer a completely new code?

Comment: well you can see yourself that the only thing which is the same is the `input()`, otherwise everything is changed. The comments in code explain it. Just copy-paste it, and it should work